# chang pictures radiobutton using php

Tags: php

I think the code is completely fine, but there is a small thing I can't find. I hope you guys can find it. I have been searching for 1 hour to find why the photo change thing doesn't work. Can you please help? Thanks a lot!

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <?php 

        if (!empty($_GET)) {            
                    $artiest = $_GET["artiest"];    
                    $single = $_GET["single"];
                        $fp = fopen("muziekcollectie.txt", "a+");
                        fputs($fp, $artiest."\r\n");
                        fputs($fp, $single."\r\n");
                        fclose($fp);
                };

        ?>




        <?php
            if(!empty($_POST))  {
                // $piz = $_GET['type'];
                if ($_POST['type'] == 'beat') {
                    echo "<img src='beat.jpg'>";
                }
                if ($_POST['type'] == 'amy') {
                    echo "<img src='amy.jpg'>";
                }
                if ($_POST['type'] == 'steve') {
                    echo "<img src='steve.jpg'>";
                }
            }

        ?>



    </head>
    <body>



        <form name="woorden" method="GET">
            Artiest:<input type="text" name="artiest"><br>
            Single:<input type="text" name="single"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add"><br><br>
        <form>




            <a href="SEB2.php">TEST</a><br><br>




            <form method="POST">
                <input type="radio" value="beat" name="type">The Beatles<br>
                <input type="radio" value="amy" name="type">Amy Winehouse<br>
                <input type="radio" value="steve" name="type">Steve Jobs<br>
                <input type="submit" name="Verander" value="Verander"><br>
            </form>

        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: are you trying to put an image tag in the head of a html file?

Comment: into the site just all the way at the top

Comment: then move your php code down after opening the body tag

Comment: still not working

Comment: you have one too many closing form tag at the end. also make sure the image paths are correct. the way you declare their paths, they would have to be in the same folder as this php file

Comment: oh isee thanks alot cashbee

Comment: does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

- You dont want to put an image tag into the head of the HTML, so move your php part down after you open the body tag.
- remove the last closing form tag at the bottom, you already closed all your forms.